# Error with time.strptime() and python-twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I use [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) to get the date of a tweet and try to parse it with the `time.strptime()` function. When I do it interactively, everything works fine. When I call the program from my bash, I get a `ValueError` saying (for example):

```
time data u'Wed Aug 12 08:43:35 +0000 2009' does not match 
          format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'
```

Code looks like this:

```
api = twitter.Api(username='username', password='pw')
user = api.GetUser(username)
latest = user.GetStatus()
date = latest.GetCreatedAt()
date_struct = time.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
```

which throws the exception mentioned above.

It works on the interactive shell:

```
>>> user = api.GetUser('username')
>>> latest = user.GetStatus()
>>> date = latest.GetCreatedAt()
>>> date
u'Wed Aug 12 08:15:10 +0000 2009'
>>>> struct = time.strptime(date, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
>>>> struct
time.struct_time(tm_year=2009, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=8, tm_min=15, tm_sec=10, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=224, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Someone any idea why this is happening?

I am Using Ubuntu 9.04, Python 2.6.2 and python-twitter 0.6. All files in unicode.

Comment: Do you perhaps have different versions of python running? Compare the output of sys.version for both the interactive shell and the bash shell's default interpreter.

Comment: No, interactive shell says "2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:56:41) \n[GCC 4.3.3]" and Bash says (python --version) "Python 2.6.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to try:

(1) Is it possible that your interactive session and your "bash" are using different locales? Put `print time.strftime(some known struct_time)` into your script and see if the day and month come out in a different language.

(2) Put `print repr(date)` in your script to show unambiguously what you are getting from the `latest.GetCreatedAt()` call.

Comment: (1) helped to solve the problem. thanks a lot! 
test = time.gmtime()
print time.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y', test)
printed it in my locale (de_DE), so for example 'Wed' for Wednesday was 'Mit' for Mittwoch. That caused strptime() to fail.
I set locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C'), which is working for the moment. I will have a deeper look into this issue some time later. Thanks again!